# How do I change the distribution of a remote server myself?

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I rent a cheap bare metal server with a fresh debian of which I have root access over ssh and no physical access ; and for some purpose I'd like it to run Fedora.

The server does not have any LOM-system.

How can I replace the debian by a fedora on my server ?

One of the features I want from fedora is selinux, which is compiled into the kernel

Comment: "_One of the features I want from fedora is selinux, which is compiled into the kernel_" It's on [Debian too](https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup). Just not enabled by default

Comment: You might also be able to ask the provider if they'll install Fedora for you

Answer (score 2):

You could `chroot` into a directory that has a Fedora installation.
E.g: https://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-run-multiple-linux-distros-without-virtualization/

Alternatively, could you install Docker on that Debian server, and then just `docker pull fedora`?

Comment: That's pretty interesting, but I do need some kernel features from fedora, such as selinux (and kvm, but it's on debian as well)